# android ink note taking with hyperlinks

Tags: android, note-taking, hyperlink

There are plenty of note taking apps for Android that allow one to use tablet ink to create notes.  I'm looking for one that also supports the creation of hyperlinks to specific places in the current or other native documents created by the app.  It must be possible to create a hyperlink that is attached to any object directly in the document, although in practice as long as I can attach a link to any rectangular region that will be sufficient.   The target of the hyperlink may support external URLs, but it absolutely must support linking to specific location (page and position) and zoom levels in the current document or other documents created by the app.  It must be possible to follow the link by tapping directly on the object or region, although it would be necessary to select a different (non-editing) mode first.

App can be free or for pay.

Intuitive, out of the box use (e.g. things like pinch to pan/zoom) as well as responsive ink are also important.  Ideally the app is lightweight and self-contained, and doesn't *require* me to (e.g.) obtain a sign in just to use it.

Here is a survey of note taking apps which I have tried which don't appear meet my needs:

1. [Metamoji Note](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metamoji.noteanytime2)
   Supports creating hyperlinks (called "jumps") but they exist at the document level - you have to create and access them in a side bar; it isn't possible to tap directly on an object in the document to activate them.  Furthermore, there isn't any indication of what the jump goes to aside from a thumbnail of the target, which can be difficult to distinguish when the jumps are all hand-written notes.
2. [ColorNote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note)
   It's possible to create a hyperlink to another note, but it is necessary to use wiki markup, and it only links to a note, not a specific page, pan, and zoom level in that note.
3. [Lecture Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acadoid.lecturenotes)
   I found this app relatively unintuitive to use (it wasn't immediately obvious how to pan or zoom), and the ink lagged noticably behind my stylus.   There [appears](http://lecturenotes.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_started) to be a way to create links, but it seems to require manually typing in a long path, and does not appear to support pan/zoom in the page, nor the ability to associate the link with an arbitrary object or rectangle.
4. Evernote appears to require that you enter hyperlinks on a PC, and OneNote doesn't support internal hyperlinks on the mobile version. I can't begin to describe how unacceptable this is.

Comment: So basically some [wiki-style](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_106) or [markdown-style](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_107) editor?

Comment: @Izzy no, i want to enter everything with digital ink... handwriting, diagrams, etc.  it doesn't have to recognize any of it and convert it to something else though.

Comment: Then I must pass. I'm not aware of any handwriting OCR app that would fit (if such exists at all), sorry.

Comment: @Izzy doesn't have to recognize... i.e. I don't care about OCR

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I need, and what I started searching for (the search even landed me on this page)! Did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: @IvanŠ Sorry, I did not.

Comment: @michael After writing that comment I found Supernote A5X, it supports exactly what you outlined here, and I ended up ordering it. Btw what tablet/program did you end up going with? Ivan

Comment: @IvanŠ That's interesting, looks like a dedicated hardware platform... i wound up going with nothing, because i couldn't find what I was looking for, but I'll have to take a look at the Supernotes when they aren't sold out.

Comment: @IvanŠ Can you point me to where it mentions link creation?  I don't see it in the online manual linked from the web site...